# Convert SWF to PNG image with transparency

Tags: c#, .net, image, flash, transparency

I'm converting a `swf` file to `png` image using [SWFtoImage](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/swftovideosdk/swftovideosdk.html) tool in c#. I'm able to convert the file successfully, but the problem is transparency. The converted image contains a `black background` instead of `transparent`, as you can see in the attached image.

[image]

how can I fix this? since the tool fails to create a transparent image, is it possible in .net to manipulate on the `converted png image` and make its background transparent?

**Current Code:**

```
        //Namespace: BytescoutSWFToVideo;

        // Create an instance of SWFToVideo ActiveX object
        SWFToVideo converter = new SWFToVideo();

        // Register SWFToVideo
        converter.RegistrationName = "demo";
        converter.RegistrationKey = "demo";

        // set input SWF file
        converter.InputSWFFileName = @"D:\image2069.swf";

        // Enable trasparency
        converter.RGBAMode = true;

        // Extract all frames to .\Output sub-folder
        converter.ConvertAllToPNG(@"D:\Result\");
```

[This is the swf file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/qx0qq2).

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `c#` and `.net`?

Comment: because, I want it to be done in c#; `is it possible in .net to manipulate on the converted png image and make its background transparent?`

Comment: OK, so how does your current code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about SWFToImage. But the company's web site contains demo code with the following comment (translated to C#):

```
// Enable trasparency - set BEFORE setting input SWF filename
converter.RGBAMode = true;
```

So possibly you have to change the order of your statements.